# how I get view data using DataContext of apache meta modal?

Tags: java, csv, apache-metamodel

I have create sample program using DataContext class for get all information of tables and write into csv file.Can I use DataContext or any other options in java for getting information of all views?
  **My sample code for getting table and write into csv.**

```
           UpdateableDataContext dataContext = DataContextFactory.createCsvDataContext(tmpCSV);
           TableCreationBuilder table = callback.createTable(getDataContext().getDefaultSchema(),"Table1").execute();
           RowInsertionBuilder insert = callback.insertInto(table);
    //we are getting each column from each record and than run
           insert.value("columnName","value")
//After inserting all records we are execute below command to insert data into csv
           insert.execute();
```

Please suggest how can I use DataContext or other any java code for getting views and write its data in csv file.

Thanks in Advance!!